# Core.async <! channel deadlock

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Why does Alpha stop early, when I expect it to behave like Beta? The only difference between Alpha and Beta is `>!` and `put!`, as commented below.

Alpha:

```
user=> (def q (chan))
#'user/q
user=> (def counter (atom 0))
#'user/counter
user=> (defn mg [event-queue]
  #_=>      (go-loop [event (<! event-queue)]
  #_=>       (swap! counter inc)
  #_=>       (when (< @counter 4)
  #_=>         (println "counter: " @counter)
  #_=>         (>! event-queue {:a @counter})      ;; Here's the only difference
  #_=>         (println "event: " event)
  #_=>         (recur (<! event-queue)))))
#'user/mg
user=> (mg q)
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x3a1ffd56 "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@3a1ffd56"]
user=> (put! q "hi")
counter:  true
1
user=>
```

Beta:

```
user=> (def q (chan))
#'user/q
user=> (def counter (atom 0))
#'user/counter
user=> (defn mg [event-queue]
  #_=>   (go-loop [event (<! event-queue)]
  #_=>    (swap! counter inc)
  #_=>    (when (< @counter 4)
  #_=>      (println "counter: " @counter)
  #_=>      (put! event-queue {:a @counter})      ;; Here's the only difference
  #_=>      (println "event: " event)
  #_=>      (recur (<! event-queue)))))
#'user/mg
user=> (mg q)
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x72c9b65a "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@72c9b65a"]
user=> (put! q "hi")
true
counter:  1
event:  hi
counter:  2
event:  {:a 1}
counter:  3
event:  {:a 2}
user=>
```

It's also interesting that, after executing Alpha, the channel `#'user/q` was properly enqueued:

```
user=> (take! q println)
event:  hi
{:a 1}
nil
user=>
```

The same results occur in both Clojure and Clojurescript. Is this some sort of deadlock, or is the suppose to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected.

The channel `q` is created without a buffer, so when a value is placed with [`>!`](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/>!), it will block (park) the `go-loop` until another thread is ready to consume the value with `<!`.

One way to work around this is to give `q` a 1-slot buffer with `(def q (chan 1))`.  The buffer allows 1 value to be placed in the channel without blocking the sender.

Beta behaves differently because [`put!`](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/put!) is asynchronous wrt. the caller -- it uses a separate thread to place the new value in the channel.  This avoids blocking the current `go-loop`, allowing the channel to be read and progress to continue.

Comment: As an addenum, `put!` can be used outside of a `go-loop` to put things inside a channel, i.e. inside a callback. This is much more performant over creating many small `go-loop`s.